# How do i get my google map to point to the location it is supposed to?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my website, my map displays perfectly fine. However the marker i have set is in the position it is supposed to but when you load the map from the accordion, the map displays away from the specific location and marker which i have programmed it to go to. Why is it doing this and how do i go about fixing it?

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>London Tour Guide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <style>
        div.container { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 720px; height: 1300px;
            background-color: white; }

        div.content {
            width: 700px; height: 1200px;
            background-color: lightblue; padding: 5px; }

        h1.welcome {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center; text-shadow: 2px 2px Grey;
            transition: 4s;}

        h1.stpauls{font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1.welcome:hover{transform: rotateX(360deg); color:yellow; }

        p.medium {
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 color: #333;
        }

        p.small {
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 color: #333;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }


        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;

        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }


        .dropbtn1 {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        .dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }


        .dropdown1 {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }


        .dropdown1-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show{display:block;}

        button.accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        div.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
        }

        div.panel.show {
            display: block;
        }




    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class = "content">

    <div class = "header">
        <img src = "headerlondon.jpg" alt = "header"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Project.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Map.html">Maps </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="travel">Travel <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Bus.html">Bus</a>
                <a href="Taxi.html">Taxi</a>
                <a href="Tube.html">Tube</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="sightseeing">SightSeeing <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="LondonEye.html">London Eye</a>
                <a href="TowerofLondon.html">Tower of London</a>
                <a href="BigBen.html">Big Ben</a>
                <a href="StPaulsCathedral.html">St Pauls Cathedral</a>
                <a href="BuckinghamPalace.html">Buckingham Palace</a>
                <a href="WestMinister.html">WestMinister</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="Museums">Museums <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="BritishMuseum.html">British Museum</a>
                <a href="ScienceMuseum.html">Science Museum</a>
                <a href="NationalHistoryMuseum.html">National History Museumm</a>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

<button class="accordion">Navigation</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div id="map" style="left:150px;width:60%;height:300px"></div>

        </div>


</div>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }
        }

        function myMap() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myCenter,
                zoom: 10
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(1);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }, 1000);


        }

        </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E&callback=myMap"></script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Remove `myMap` from `callback`

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E"></script>
```

... and put it inside `click` event.

```
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    myMap();
}
```

Also why do you have two loops for `for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++)` and if you are planning to animate the accordion, you may need to call `myMap` after animation done.

**working snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>London Tour Guide</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <style>
        div.container { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 400px; width: 720px; height: 1300px;
            background-color: white; }

        div.content {
            width: 700px; height: 1200px;
            background-color: lightblue; padding: 5px; }

        h1.welcome {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center; text-shadow: 2px 2px Grey;
            transition: 4s;}

        h1.stpauls{font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; color: orangered;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1.welcome:hover{transform: rotateX(360deg); color:yellow; }

        p.medium {
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 color: #333;
        }

        p.small {
 font-size: 12pt;
 font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
 color: #333;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
        }


        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a, .dropbtn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;

        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;

        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }


        .dropbtn1 {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 16px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }


        .dropbtn1:hover, .dropbtn1:focus {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }


        .dropdown1 {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        }


        .dropdown1-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }


        .dropdown1-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

        .show{display:block;}

        button.accordion {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }

        button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        div.panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
        }

        div.panel.show {
            display: block;
        }




    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class = "content">

    <div class = "header">
        <img src = "headerlondon.jpg" alt = "header"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Project.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Map.html">Maps </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="travel">Travel <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Bus.html">Bus</a>
                <a href="Taxi.html">Taxi</a>
                <a href="Tube.html">Tube</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="sightseeing">SightSeeing <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="LondonEye.html">London Eye</a>
                <a href="TowerofLondon.html">Tower of London</a>
                <a href="BigBen.html">Big Ben</a>
                <a href="StPaulsCathedral.html">St Pauls Cathedral</a>
                <a href="BuckinghamPalace.html">Buckingham Palace</a>
                <a href="WestMinister.html">WestMinister</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="Museums">Museums <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="BritishMuseum.html">British Museum</a>
                <a href="ScienceMuseum.html">Science Museum</a>
                <a href="NationalHistoryMuseum.html">National History Museumm</a>

            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>

<button class="accordion">Navigation</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div id="map" style="left:150px;width:60%;height:300px"></div>

        </div>


</div>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
              myMap();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }
        }

        function myMap() {
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
          
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myCenter,
                zoom: 10
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myCenter
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(1);
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            }, 1000);


        }

        </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB37us778WYnwNjHftUm3oL2oduV_WOt_E"></script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, this works fantastically. Okay i have two loops because i want one to firstly show the map in the first place this creates the basic container for it then the second loop then resizes the map to fit within the container so that it will appear. Usually when you place a map within an accordion it will turn grey unless you resize it. I just thought that two loops would be easier to understand

Comment: @user7048814 Glad that it worked. Would be great if you accept my answer putting a green tick to the left ;)